# Background exec() and writing to disk

Tags: php, download, background-process

I have this small script (`background.php`):

```
<?php

    $url = urldecode($_SERVER['argv'][1]);
    $id = $_SERVER['argv'][2];
    $name = $id.'.mp4';
    $proof = $id.'.proof';
    
    // Download
    file_put_contents("temp/$name", fopen($url, 'r'));
    file_put_contents("temp/$proof", "");

?>
```

I want to run it in background.

## Case 1

If I do `exec('php download.php my_url id > /dev/null &');` it runs in background to but does not download anything.

## Case 2

If I do `exec('php download.php my_url id >> temp/loging.log &');` it downloads the file but not in background (while downloading my webpage is "loading").

Can anyone help me?

---

## Remark

I am running the `php` on Windows with UniServerZ.

Comment: is there a chance that the script is producing an output not redirected to your log file, such as a warning or an error? have you checked that php has permission to write in the folder and such? Did you try to produce an output to verify it is appended correctly to the log file?

Comment: The output goes indeed to the log file. The permissions: it should be ok, isn't it, since the script downloads the file in case 2.

Comment: i was more thinking about permissions to write the log, but the fact it does it answers the question.. sorry, no other idea for the moment

Comment: @Kaddath You can have a look at my answer :-) Thanks

Comment: Definetly should take the habit of thinking about windows oddities too for errors, specially when talking about servers :D

Comment: Plus the fact that I'm usually a Mac user and a newbee to server things and to php.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on Windows, this will not work.

You have to do

```
pclose(popen('start /B cmd /C "php download.php my_url id >NUL 2>NUL"', 'r'));
```

I'm not sure what `/B` and `/C` stand for.